# Como imprimir o conteúdo de uma página com Bootstrap e JQuery?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Gostaria de adicionar um botão Bootstrap para invocar a impressão de conteúdo de uma página, consegui esse exemplo, mas ele funciona a partir de um link, vejam:
[Exemplo](http://www.pinceladasdaweb.com.br/blog/uploads/print-link/)

O código posiciona o link na parte superior da página, também vi um exemplo aqui mesmo, nesse link [Exemplo Stackoverflow](http://jsfiddle.net/gFtUY/), mas não gostaria de abrir a página com conteúdo novamente, simplesmente clicar no botão, chamar a caixa de impressão e imprimir como no primeiro exemplo citado.

O código da primeiro exemplo é esse:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').prepend('Click aqui para imprimir');
    $('a#print').click(function() {
        window.print();
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se o seu objetivo é ter um botão que usa a classse do bootstrap e só usar`btn btn-primary` por exemplo, e se não quiser que abra em nova abra e so remover o `target_blank`, pelo que entendi seria algo assim:

```js
        document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
          window.print();
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<body>
  <div id="sua_div">Essa é a DIV</div>
  <button id="btn" class="btn btn-primary">Clique para imprimir</button>
</body>
```

Comment: Olá @Gabriel Rodrigues, muito obrigado pela colaboração, foi de grande ajuda.